# Transform a particular field with jq

Tags: json, transformation, jq

I have a json object with a field which can have a string or an array value.

```
{
  "roles": ["ADMIN", "USER"]
  "user_id": 100,
  "message": "abc added a user xyz",
  "level": "info",
  "created_at": "2014-10-12 14:06:37"
}
{
  "roles": "ADMIN"
  "user_id": 102,
  "message": "a added a user b",
  "level": "info",
  "created_at": "2014-10-12 14:06:37"
}
```

I want to transform roles field to a csv, and keep the rest of the fields as is.

```
{
  "roles": "ADMIN,USER"
  "user_id": 100,
  "message": "abc added a user xyz",
  "level": "info",
  "created_at": "2014-10-12 14:06:37"
}
{
  "roles": "ADMIN"
  "user_id": 102,
  "message": "a added a user b",
  "level": "info",
  "created_at": "2014-10-12 14:06:37"
}
```

I tried reading the documentation, but couldn't find a construct to just transform a single field. Can this be achieved using Jq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use the filter:

```
.roles |= if type == "array" then join(",") else . end
```

In the first example, this would produce the value: "ADMIN,USER"

A more robust filter would be:

```
.roles |= if type == "array" then map(tostring)|join(",") else . end
```

Still more robust would be to use `@csv` in the `then` clause, but this will produce more quotation marks than you might want:

```
"\"ADMIN\",\"USER\""
```

So you might want to consider using @tsv instead; it would produce:

```
"ADMIN\tUSER"
```

Comment: It worked, thanks :) In fact, I had to ask this question because `@csv` was failing for objects with array fields. So this was required to make `@csv` work.

Comment: `@csv` requires arrays of atoms (i.e. strings, numbers, booleans, nulls), so it would be interesting to know what exactly was failing.

Comment: I get this error `array (["ADMIN...) is not valid in a csv row` when running `@csv`, Object passed to it is `["2017-10-12T08:36:37.763Z", "info",  0, ["ADMIN], 1507797397763, 264074 ]`

Comment: Did you mean instead of join(",") ? I was talking about transforming the whole object to csv.. please ignore if thats the case.

Comment: Updated for clarity.